# Cannot install vim plugins in OS X

Tags: macos, vim, installation, macvim

This is what I have tried so far:

```
 - Regular .dmg install and adding the plugin.vim into the plugin directory in /Applications/mavim/Contents/Resources/runtime/plugins
 - **homebrew install macvim**. This put the macvim into usr/local/Cellar/macvim/7.4-72/MacVim.app/Contents/....
```

Now everyone seems to install the plugins into ~/.vim/ . I assume this is in your user home directory? But I don't have this folder.

I have no idea how to get the plugins to work. I can add color schemes but no plugins.

Answer (score 3):

You have to create this files and folders by yourself:

Here we go, on your terminal run a few commands:

```
$ touch .vimrc
$ touch .gvimrc
$ mkdir .vim
$ open .vim
```

Once you create .vim folder, you can simply install any bundles to this directory. I highly recommend you using [vundle](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim), it's a great Vim plugin manager.

Please go to this [link](https://github.com/gmarik/Vundle.vim), read the instruction on how to install Vundle. This pretty much what you need to know about vim plugin installation.

You can also edit your .vimrc file to change your vim configuration to initialize vim when it starts.

First you need to cd home directory where vim located:

```
$ cd $HOME
```

Open .vimrc:

```
$ vim .vimrc
```

Add a few scripts to see what has changed in your vim:

`i.e:`

```
 syntax on
 set number
 set ruler
 set background=dark
```

Then save by pressing `Esc` then `:wq`

For more config on vim go to [vim wikia](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Vim_Tips_Wiki).

Cheer :)